# Given an 1d and nd array, find out the next smaller and larger elements

Tags: python-3.x, numpy-ndarray

Suppose I have the below nd and 1d array

```
arr_nd = [[ 1  2  3]
          [ 4  5  6]
          [ 7  8  9]
          [21 22 23]]

arr_1d = [[ 7.5  2.5  6.5]]
```

When I compare **arr_1d** with **arr_nd** I should get the below output

The next smaller elements comparing **arr_1d** with **arr_nd** is

```
arr_smaller = [[7, 2, 6]]
```

The next larger elements comparing **arr_1d** with **arr_nd** is

```
arr_larger = [[21, 5, 9]]
```

What's the most efficient pythonic way to do the above.

Comment: CVan you ex[plain the logic behind the transformation from arr_1d * arr_nd to arr_smaller, and arr_larger?

Answer (score 0):

I would do smth like this:

```
arr_smaller = np.zeros_like(arr_nd, float)
arr_smaller[...] = np.nan
arr_smaller[(arr_nd.T<arr_1d.reshape(-1, 1)).T] = arr_nd[(arr_nd.T<arr_1d.reshape(-1, 1)).T]
arr_smaller = np.nanmax(arr_smaller.T, 1)

arr_larger = np.zeros_like(arr_nd, float)
arr_larger[...] = np.nan
arr_larger[(arr_nd.T>arr_1d.reshape(-1, 1)).T] = arr_nd[(arr_nd.T>arr_1d.reshape(-1, 1)).T]
arr_larger = np.nanmin(arr_larger.T, 1)
```

output:

```
arr_smaller = [7. 2. 6.]
arr_larger = [21.  5.  9.]
```